# can we set specific branch to clone when someone form our repo?

Tags: github

I want to give acess to my collegue and ask to fork my repo but it fork the complete repo ( which is what fork is) and it clone the default branch, **main** ( assuming I havnt changed default branch)

So my question is, can we set specific branch of a repo while forking , keeping default branch *main*

is ther any setting available in github.com?